# How to save the last image of a matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how to save the last image of a `FuncAnimation` in Python 3. Here's some code:

```
import matplotlib.animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_2d_graph, frames=9, interval=600, repeat_delay=5000, blit=False)
ani.save(output_dir, writer="imagemagick")
```

where `_update_2d_graph` is a function providing different offsets of points depending on the frame number:

```
def _update_2d_graph(num):
    x_updated = np.hstack((pos_gt.x[:num].tolist(),pos_pred.x[:num].tolist()))
    y_updated = np.hstack((pos_gt.y[:num].tolist(),pos_pred.y[:num].tolist()))

    paths_gt = []
    paths_ped = []

    for i in range(num):
        marker_gt = mmarkers.MarkerStyle('o')
        marker_ped = mmarkers.MarkerStyle('x')
        path_gt = marker_gt.get_path().transformed(marker_gt.get_transform())
        path_ped = marker_ped.get_path().transformed(marker_ped.get_transform())
        paths_gt.append(path_gt)
        paths_ped.append(path_ped)

    graph._paths = np.concatenate([paths_gt, paths_ped])
    graph.set_facecolors(np.concatenate([colors[:num], colors[:num]]))
    graph.set_edgecolors(np.concatenate([colors[:num], colors[:num]]))
    graph.set_offsets(np.hstack((y_updated[:, np.newaxis], x_updated[:, np.newaxis])))
```

Instead of saving the entire animation (e.g. as .gif file), I want to save a .png of the last time step of the animation. 
**Is it possible to access the last frame within the animation object?**

I don't want to call `_update_2d_graph(9)` since this call has already been executed by the animation object nor do I want to re-iterate over the entire 9 frames through another `FuncAnimation` call.

Comment: Please provide the code (or a simplified form thereof) for `_update_2d_graph`, the answer will likely depend on how you wrote that function. It could be as simple as running `update_2d_graph(9)` to get the last frame, or you may have to iterate through all the frame to get the final result

Comment: @DizietAsahi Asahi done

Comment: I don't understand why you would run the animation to let it do nothing and save the last frame. If you just want to save the last frame, you would remove the complete animation (`ani = ....`) and call `_update_2d_graph(8); fig.savefig(...)` to save the last frame.

Comment: This example does not show my full use case. In my full use case, I have created a animation to store an animation as a .gif. My idea was now, since the object has already been created, to ideally use the animation object again to access the last frame to store a .png in addition to the .gif. I guess I was assuming there was an easy way to access this information inside the object without iterating again.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I've tried clarifying my question.

Comment: The `FuncAnimation` does not store each individual frame (that would be pretty memory expensive, however a `ArtistAnimation` would do that). What is the reason for "I don't want to call _update_2d_graph(9)"? (also (9) hasn't been called, (8) would be the last frame,right?)

Comment: my bad, I was the one that wrote `9` instead of `8` for the last frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, my initial tests suggest that just saving the figure after running the animation does save the last frame state. Can you test it to confirm?

```
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_2d_graph, frames=9, interval=600, repeat_delay=5000, blit=False)
ani.save(output_dir, writer="imagemagick")
fig.savefig('last_frame.png')
```

I used the code from the [Animated 3D random walk example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/random_walk.html#animated-3d-random-walk):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def Gen_RandLine(length, dims=2):
    """
    Create a line using a random walk algorithm

    length is the number of points for the line.
    dims is the number of dimensions the line has.
    """
    lineData = np.empty((dims, length))
    lineData[:, 0] = np.random.rand(dims)
    for index in range(1, length):
        # scaling the random numbers by 0.1 so
        # movement is small compared to position.
        # subtraction by 0.5 is to change the range to [-0.5, 0.5]
        # to allow a line to move backwards.
        step = ((np.random.rand(dims) - 0.5) * 0.1)
        lineData[:, index] = lineData[:, index - 1] + step

    return lineData


def update_lines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines):
        # NOTE: there is no .set_data() for 3 dim data...
        line.set_data(data[0:2, :num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2, :num])
    return lines

# Attaching 3D axis to the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

# Fifty lines of random 3-D lines
data = [Gen_RandLine(25, 3) for index in range(50)]

# Creating fifty line objects.
# NOTE: Can't pass empty arrays into 3d version of plot()
lines = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1], dat[2, 0:1])[0] for dat in data]

# Setting the axes properties
ax.set_xlim3d([0.0, 1.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([0.0, 1.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([0.0, 1.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.set_title('3D Test')

# Creating the Animation object
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_lines, 25, fargs=(data, lines),
                                   interval=50, blit=False, repeat=True)

### HERE ARE THE ONLY LINES I ADDED ####
line_ani.save('./test.gif', writer='imagemagick')
fig.savefig('./test.png')
```

file `test.gif`

[image]

file `test.png`

[image]